# Linux - How to copy a list of files with special characters to new directory

Tags: linux, file-management

I have a list of files with paths, some of the files have special characters such as spaces, hyphens, single or double quotes like the following:

```
/Music/Allman_Brothers/Filmore_east/The Allman Brothers Band - At The Fillmore East (Disc 2) - 02 - In Memory of Elizabeth Reed.mp3
```

This is actually a playlist. What I need to do is copy the files in this playlist into a single directory. I have tried using xargs without any luck, probably because I haven't used the proper options. :)  Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On GNU xargs – the one that Linux uses – you can use `-d` to specify the delimiter:

```
xargs -d '\n' mv --target somedir/ < playlist.txt
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. I forgot about the newline. Thanks a lot.   :)